# How to run a one-time 'setup' step for amrfinder in snakemake using conda

Tags: snakemake, conda, hpc

I'm trying to add [amrfinder](https://github.com/ncbi/amr) running within conda to a snakemake workflow, working on a slurm HPC.

The first time you run `amrfinder`, you have to run `amrfinder -u` to update/download the database of genes/proteins which it searches for. Since I'm using the `--use-conda` flag of `snakemake`, the first time I run the workflow, it creates a new env for the `conda` package, so this command has to be run before that copy of `amrfinder` will work.

My question is: how do I run `amrfinder -u` within `snakemake`? If I do it as part of the standard `amrfinder` command, it runs as many times as there are samples, and as all the jobs are looking at the same database, when it updates for one job, it breaks the other jobs.

I can't figure out how to run this command in a 'snakemake-y' way, as it has no input, it's just literally `amrfinder -u`.

Of course, I can make it work with a hack/workaround, but I'm interested in a snakemake way of doing it.

This is the main snakemake rule for running amr_finder_plus, the new rule, to run `amrfinder -u` needs to run before this

```
rule amr_finder_plus:
    input:
        assembly = 'my_assembly.fasta'
    output:
        amr_finder_plus_results = 'my_amr_finder_plus_results.tsv'
    conda:
        '../../envs/amrfinderplus.yaml'
    shell:
        'amrfinder -n {input.assembly} -O Salmonella --output {output.amr_finder_plus_results} --threads 4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take:

1. There's a `--conda-create-envs-only` option that you can use to exit after creating the envs. You should get information about where the envs are so you can run `amrfinder -u`.
2. Add a new rule called "amr_setup" or something like that that runs:

.

```
amrfinder -u
touch amrfinder.setup
```

Then put `amrfinder.setup` into your snakemake workflow as an input file into the amr_finder_plus rule. Either of these will work